# Google Compute Engine: in your experience, is f1-micro free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Does anyone have billing-related experience with the `f1-micro` VM instance on Google Cloud Platform?

I observe from the document on [always-free GCP services](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) that in certain regions, it is free (up to certain limits). At the same time, when I go to my GCP portal and start setting up such a machine, I see that the projected cost for the month is $4.28:

[image]

I looks as though it possibly would not actually impose a charge if it was the only `f1-micro` on my account for a given month. Have you used this?

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is a charge but a more nominal one that what you face. Why stress over it when any google account is allotted a 12 month $300 usage credit?? I run a high performance marketplace instance for about $15/mo at standard n1 resources.